# Textfileprocessing by negative value

Tags: batch-file

I got the following textfile. I want to parse trough and put all lines with a negative input in one textfile and all positive in an other. How to manage that ?

help apreciated

```
   39.93120000     14318.98314981793         549.1248138635204
   39.93480000     14207.58401258784         533.3688586990800
   39.93840000     14668.87500855270         506.8355357433776
   39.94200000     14364.81298137747         523.5021767630467
   39.94560000     14345.01825913795         522.9223798929314
   39.94920000     14266.44146878225         568.0035355907847
   39.95280000     14575.20734902781         593.3706907927941
   39.95640000     14588.52376078192         610.6837211933131
   39.96000000     14332.24884001532         388.5737178283878
   39.96360000     14533.92791344165         539.5396926983177
   39.96720000     14350.80457814612         510.0423201220646
   -39.97080000     14196.71360046875         514.3275994436243
   -39.97440000     14051.71265422134         527.4882736778169
   -39.97800000     14038.57270550476         503.0691346196745
   -39.98160000     14359.74967748116         520.6326881374556
   -39.98520000     14710.85875093256         516.4180753359947
   -39.98880000     14266.49788517777         690.0481714109405
   -39.99240000     14198.67205164648         608.3535256285546
   -39.99600000     14417.30585582810         662.5276659319838
   -39.99960000     14615.74632666744         599.8846644801356
```

batch so far, the var test isnt giving me an output of the first character of the line

```
cls
@echo off

SET sourcefile=sourcefile.txt

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%sourcefile%) do (

    for /F "tokens=*" %%B in (%%A) do (
        SET leadingLetter= %%B:~0,1%
        echo %leadingLetter%

    )

)
```

Comment: There are lots of possibilities. I see you've tagged the question "batch-file" - do you want a DOS / Windows command batch specifically, or could you use eg a Python, Perl, sed etc. solution?

Comment: i want to do it with batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you are processing full lines, so this will do what you seem to be asking.

```
@echo off
find "-" <filein.txt >negative.txt
find /v "-" <filein.txt >positive.txt
```